# Crop a image in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-native-image

I'm referring to the image via `require` and I wanted to crop the icons from the sprite image.

```
const sprite = require('./sprite.png')
const crop = {left: 10, top: 50, width: 20, height: 40}

export const cartLogo = sprite({crop})
// How do I apply the crop to the sprite?

then

<Image source={cartLogo}/>
```

I see how to crop the image in react-native when using `{uri: 'url-to-image', crop: {left: 10, top: 50, width: 20, height: 40}}` [in here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#source-as-an-object). How to do it with `require`?.

Answer (score 0):

I know that require('./sprite.png') will be depreciated soon.

So the best way it's to managed it with

```
image : {uri: ..., crop: {left: 10, top: 50, width: 20, height: 40}}
```

You can also follow [my post here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42331823/crop-image-with-react-native/42332517#42332517)

let us know if you success

Comment: Was `require('./sprite.png')` ever deprecated?

I'm not sure how to use your answer.  Is this a property of `<Image />`?

I've read your post, which references the docs, which don't give any examples of how to use it (the use of `static` confuses me).